# Fputs insertig invalid data at the beginning

Tags: c

My input file containing collection of products in this format:

```
name
price
symbol
```

Example file is:

```
Ball
6.24
u
```

I want to read file, parse text to `struct`, and rewrite file with same elements, but without those with symbol `u`.
This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

struct Product
{
    char name[30];
    char amount;
    double price;
};

int main()
{
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    struct Product products[100];

    fp = fopen("magazyn.txt", "r+");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    int counter = 0;
    int amount = 0;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        if (counter != 0 && counter % 3 == 0)
        {
            counter = 0;
            amount++;
        }

            if (counter % 3 == 0) {
                strcpy(products[amount].name, line);
            }

            if (counter % 3 == 1)
                products[amount].price = atof(line);

            if (counter % 3 == 2)
                products[amount].amount = line[0];

        counter++;
    }

    truncate("magazyn.txt", 0);

    for(int i=0; i<amount; i++)
    {
        if (products[amount].amount != 'u') 
        {
            fprintf(fp, "%s\n%lf\n%c\n", 
            products[amount].name,
            products[amount].price,
            products[amount].amount);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    if (line)
        free(line);

    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, I am getting `\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00\00Ball`. Why is that happening?

Comment: I don't see `fputs` anywhere in your code

Comment: Unrelated, but your `counter` is going from `0` to `2` anyway, so there is no reason for all of these `% 3` calculations.

Comment: What is `truncate()`? What was its return value? If you want to overwrite the file it would be usual to seek to the start of the file first, and only trim the excess length of the file after the writing is done.

Comment: @Govind Parmar there is fprintf..

Comment: @dafie Indeed, but your question title said "fputs" which was misleading

Comment: @WeatherVane with `fseek(fp,0,0)` I am getting `《〮〰〰ਰ਀《〮〰〰ਰ਀u` at the begginng. Rest lines are ok.

Comment: `SEEK_SET` doesn't have to be defined as `0`

Comment: I manually set `SEEK_SET` but still hetting bricked data at the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

Code is reading some lines from a file then append new lines to the same file (yes, it appends, see below).

Calling `truncate()` set the file size to 0 on the filesystem. But it doesn't reset the current file offset for the opened file.

So when writing the new lines, they're appended at the end of the previous content, while previous content is replaced by 0: it's creating a sparse file, a file with hole, hole filled with 0.